# Codecademy How does print_board() function creates a row? isn't it supposed to take item by item (,)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, for-loop

```
board = []

for i in range(5):
  board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board_in):
  for row in board:
    print(row)

print_board(board)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but there are two mistakes: `print row` should be `print(row)` and within the function it makes more sense to iterate over the argument rather then over the global var: `for row in board_in:`

Answer (score 1):

`print_board` function doesn't create row, You already created list of lists(row of rows) and passing it as an argument to `print_board` function. It means `for` loop is iterating on list objects not individual elements.